# How to get value previous month & week?

Tags: postgresql

Right now I'm getting an average for each month

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AS month,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time) AS year,
       avg("total")
FROM my_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time)
```

But the SQL query needs to adjust so the `total value current month - previous month`

Is it possible?

For weekly

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date_time) AS week,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time) AS year,
       avg("total")
FROM my_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date_time), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
SELECT t1.month, t2.year, t1.tot - t2.tot FROM
(
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time) AS year, avg("total") AS tot
FROM my_table GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time)
) t1
join (
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time) AS year, avg("total") AS tot
FROM my_table GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time)
) t2
on ((t1.year = t2.year) and (t1.month = t2.month + 1)) or
   ((t1.year = t2.year + 1) and (t1.month = 1) and (t2.month = 12))
```

I have taken your `select` and converted it into two subselects, named them as `t1` and `t2` respectively and joined them by the criteria of left join.

Note that the very first month will not have a pair currently and if you need it nevertheless, then you can use `left join` and `coalesce` to make sure that even an unpaired item has a "pair" and a `NULL` for `tot` is defaulted to 0.

Note further that you can convert this subquery to a `view` for better readability.

Comment: is it same for weekly? I already updated my question above

Comment: I got error message LINE 3:  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR F...

Comment: @Nurdin the idea is the same for weeks as for month. As about the error that you get, the script I have written was untested, so there might be typos. Can you tell me the exact error?

Comment: this one LINE 3: SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR F...

Comment: @Nurdin this is not the full error, it is a chunk of it only and it is meaningless, because it only says that the error is in line 3, but from the text above it is not obvious what the error is on line 3.

Comment: @Nurdin I see I have missed a `FROM`. Nice catch and thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

If I get that correctly, you can first group avg(total) by yer and month, and the use LAG() window function to get previous month value, something like:

```
with my_table(date_time, total) as (
    values
    ('2022-03-29', 10),
    ('2022-04-29', 12),
    ('2022-05-30', 20),
    ('2022-05-31', 30)
)
,grouped as (
    SELECT EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM date_time::timestamp) AS month, EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM date_time::timestamp) AS year, avg("total") AS total
    FROM my_table 
    GROUP BY EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM date_time::timestamp) , EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM date_time::timestamp)
)
SELECT *,  LAG(total) OVER(ORDER BY year, month) as prev_month_total
FROM grouped
```